# rpy2 is working fine in console but not working in executable file

Tags: python, r, rpy2, anaconda3

i'm using rpy2 in spyder 4. all commands are working fine in console. i created an executable with pyinstaller and i got this error in exe file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kopa.py", line 12, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rpy2'
[13148] Failed to execute script kopa
```

I will give an example to be short;

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3' 
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/rpy2'

import rpy2.robjects as ro

ro.r("x=c(1,2,3,4,5)")
ro.r("y=c(11,12,13,14,15)")
ro.r("z=mean(x)+mean(y)")
print(ro.r("z"))
```

all working fine in console. when i create executable file then i'm getting the above error. where is the problem?

Comment: Can you add the part of the code where you are trying to call rpy2 module?

Comment: i added an example on my message.